# Google Cloud function local dir image reading error in pdfmake node js library

Tags: google-cloud-functions, pdfmake

I'm using pdfmake nodejs library in google cloud function for generating pdf files.

i'm downloading a image to local temp dir and using that image in pdfmake and also i've deployed a local image with the function itself and also using that image in the pdf as well.

The downloaded image is located on "/tmp/image1.png" and the local image is located on "res/image2.png"

while testing with local emulator, the code doesn't have any issue at all, but when i try to run in cloud function production environment, i'm getting following errors,

Invalid image: Error: Unknown image format.Images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)

i've deployed close to 14 version to cloud functions iterating image formats,filenames,only using local image ,only using downloaded image on tmp folder, but no luck.

When the same function is working on local emulator without any issue, i believe it must be something do to with the cloud function read and write permission.

Following it the dependency,

```
"dependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "open": "^7.3.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.69"
  },
```

following code is to download image from link to temp folder,

```
var path = require('path');
import http from 'http'
import https from 'https'
import { createWriteStream, unlink } from 'fs'

const tempDir = os.tmpdir()
const tempFileName = path.join(tempDir, 'Pic.png')
var url = "https://someimageurl"
var outFileName = path.join(tempDir, 'out.pdf')
var tradeMark = "res/mark.png"
var imageSize = 75
var downloadPic = ''





const proto = !url.charAt(4).localeCompare('s') ? https : http;

function makePdf(){
    var fonts = {
        Roboto: {
            normal: 'fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
            bold: 'fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
            italics: 'fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
            bolditalics: 'fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
        },
        Algerian: {
            normal: 'fonts/Algerian.ttf',
            bold: 'fonts/Algerian.ttf',
            italics: 'fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
            bolditalics: 'fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
        }
    };
    
    var pdfMakePrinter = require('./node_modules/pdfmake/src/printer');

        var printer = new pdfMakePrinter(fonts);
        var docDefinition = {
            pageOrientation: 'landscape',
            pageMargins: [20, 10, 20, 0],
            content: [
                {
                    columns: [
                        {
                            image: downloadPic,
                            fit: [imageSize, imageSize],
                            width: 'auto'
                        },
                        [{
                            text: "name",
                            style: { bold: true, fontSize: 30, font: 'Algerian', color: 'green' },
                            alignment: 'center',
                            width: '*',
                        },
                        {
                            text: "sub Header",
                            style: { bold: true, fontSize: 20, font: 'Roboto', color: 'green' },
                            alignment: 'center',
                            width: '*',
                            margin: [0, 5, 0, 10]
                        },
                        ],
                        {
                            image: tradeMark,
                            fit: [imageSize - 25, imageSize - 25],
                            width: 'auto',
                            margin: [0, 12, 0, 0]
                        },
            
                    ],
                    columnGap: 20
                }
            ]
        };
        
        var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
        pdfDoc.pipe(createWriteStream(outFileName));
        pdfDoc.end();
}

function downloadAndPrepareReport(url, filePath) {

    console.log("Going to download image file: url: " + url + " filePath: " + filePath)

    const proto = !url.charAt(4).localeCompare('s') ? https : http;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const file = createWriteStream(filePath);
        let fileInfo = null;

        const request = proto.get(url, response => {
            if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                console.log("Image Download failed")
                reject(new Error(`Failed to get '${url}' (${response.statusCode})`));
                return;
            }

            fileInfo = {
                mime: response.headers['content-type'],
                size: parseInt(response.headers['content-length'], 10),
            };

            response.pipe(file);
        });

        file.on('finish', () => {
                console.log("Image Download Complete")
                downloadPic = filePath
            
                makePdf()
                resolve("ok done")
            
        }

        

    );

        request.on('error', err => {
            unlink(filePath, () => reject(err));
        });

        file.on('error', err => {
            unlink(filePath, () => reject(err));
        });

        request.end();
    });
}

downloadAndPrepareReport(url,tempFileName)
```

Comment: It does not look like cloud function... what is the trigger of it?

Comment: It's a https trigger.All the assigned variables will be coming from data object.Actually my function has big code so I've only pasted the necessary information here. Thanks.